# Spring Cache Refresh Interval

Tags: caching, ehcache

I'm encounter the ehcache spring annotation project which allow the cache to be refresh.

[Article](http://cleancode.se/2012/03/31/refreshing-caches-in-ehcache.html)

Is there anything similar in Spring @Cacheable annotation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no similar approach in Spring @cacheable annotation.